# how do I transform Simplified chinese to Traditional chinese in R?

Tags: r, csv

`write.csv(place,"C:/users/sean/desktop/test.csv",row.names = FALSE)`

I have trouble to write Simplified chinese into .CSV file.

object 'place' is a Simplified chinese list :

"三亚""苏梅岛""帕劳""巴厘岛""韩国""台湾""拉萨""首尔""新西兰""云南""丽江""九寨沟"

but it will be Garbled like this :

三U+4E9A , U+82CF梅U+5C9B , 帕U+52B3 , 巴厘U+5C9B U+53A6 U+95E8 , 台 U+6E7E ,拉U+8428 , 首U+5C14 , 新西U+5170 , 云南 , U+4E3D江 , 九寨U+6C9F

Are there any packages can transform Simplified chinese to Traditional chinese in R,or any method that I can use to?

Comment: I could not find an R package which can do this.  However, Google offers a package written in Java called [java-zhconverter](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-zhconverter/downloads) which can do this.  You can call Java from R and achieve what you want.

Comment: If I just want to write in Simplified chinese,is there any method can do?
just let it don't be garbled！

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `fileEncoding` argument?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried this R package called (ropencc) before?
You may try the following code see if it works or not.

devtools::install_github("qinwf/ropencc")
 library(ropencc)
 converter(S2T)["开放中文转换"]
[1] "開放中文轉換"

However, if your Operating System is windows then you may need to install the Rtools.
Hope it helps.